# GMImagePicker causes application crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, nsdocumentdirectory

I use GMImagePicker and when i select more than 50 images from camera role the application going to be crash and it gives error like

```
 Received memory warning.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
It uses very high memory. 
The code i did

```
 - (void)assetsPickerController:(GMImagePickerController *)pickerdidFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)assetArray{

    self.requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    self.requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    self.requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

    // this one is key
    self.requestOptions.synchronous = true;

    //  self.assets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:assets];
    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    Albumimages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[assetArray count]];

    // assets contains PHAsset objects.
    __block UIImage *ima;

    for (PHAsset *asset in assetArray) {
        // Do something with the asset

        [manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                           targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                          contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                              options:self.requestOptions
                        resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                            ima = image;

                            [Albumimages addObject:ima];

                        }];


    }

NSLog(@"%@",Albumimages);

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The application crashed in for loop.

Comment: You to provide more information. Where does it crash. What does the code look like. And how are you handling the pictures after selection ?

Comment: What problem?  You are describing your issue in words not in Objective-C.  What do you mean by large size?  2 MB?  10 MB?  What do you mean by large number?  100?  1,000?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I got the problem.it is in image picker when it populate array in for loop. Please advice me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will obviously crash as you are picking 50 photos at once. just think in terms of RAM allocation. Lets assume each photo is 5 MB in size so 50*5 MB = 250 MB.OS will not provide enough ram and you are receiving memory warning due to this. See whatsapp and other apps allowed 10 images max.
may be you could try the same approach.

Comment: yes that is true.But i want unlimited selection from camera roll,not limited just 10. can you help me

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya sorry bro nobody can help you in this due to memory limitations. You need to think of some another approach.

Comment: My app have functionality like Photo Vault which store photos. for that i need all this stuff. can you suggest me or any idea about that. if you check some photo vault app they provide this type of facility.

Comment: any name of photo vault app ?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/private-photo-vault-safe-photo+video/id417571834?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya I have checked the app and I think  the app is using Assessts Library for displaying and retrieving photos from album and then it is saving all photos in it's document directory. May be you can optimize your code further to get photos 1 by 1 and save them 1 by 1 into documents direcotry. You can also read NSInputStream and OutputStream to get image data in chunks and write the data to documents directory. Search for this and you will find something for sure.

Comment: can you suggest me any example how can i write or get images using NSInputStream and OutputStream from document directory.